# How to set up remote debugging for .NET in a simple workgroup scenario?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, remote-debugging

Remote debugging is an essential tool for most programming today. However, setting it in the most simple scenarios is always somewhat of a pain.

Google and SO have answers for most pains, but there's no simple list of do a,b,c and it'll work.

Would you please suggest such a list?
I posted my own list, but I believe there are things I've missed, or that can be done better. If you have such a list please post it too.

(There might be some such lists, but let's have several here on SO)

Comment: There is no simple lists of a,b,c because Visual Studio Remote Debugger relies on DCOM. And when you are dealing with DCOM security nothing is simple :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Copy remote debugger redist to target machine and run the debugger. Note that you need the build that fits the target machine (x86, x64, ia64).
2. In the default security mode, the instance is written as user@machine.
3. In Visual Studio, enter the instance name user@machine.
4. The remote machine firewall needs to be configured to allow remote debug. Usually, the debugger suggests to auto config it.
5. The local machine also needs to be configured to allow remote debugging. Usually it means opening  TCP port 135 (DCOM) for incoming connections.
6. The local instance must run under a user that has connection privileges to the remote machine.
7. The remote instance must also run under a user that is allowed to connect to the local machine.
8. 6, 7 are easily solved if it's possible to run the instance under the same user or, in a workgroup scenario, a user with the same credentials (username, password).

Comment: So is this the answer? Or just an appendix to the question? :)

Comment: It's one suggested answer. I promise to accept the best one, even if it's not mine... especially if it's not mine!

Comment: Yep and it works, but there's more than one "simple" scenario, and several possible configurations.

Comment: Seems as though you've posted a question to which you already know the answer... what other scenario is there beyond "Debugger and debuggee?"

Comment: @Dan other security issues. I know I've had some. Wish I had written them down... One I can think of now is sometimes you can't change the user at the debuggee, but that's fairly simple to solve.

Comment: Well, without specific issues to answer, this question seems pretty vague!